# GAMS summing over subset

Tags: gams

I am trying to sum over a subset between $t+1$ and $t+U-1$ as follows $$y_i^t+\sum_{k=t+1}^{t+Ut_i-1}z_i^k\le1$$ but I could not define the condition within `sum`.

Here is what I have tried:

`y(i,t) + sum(t $(ord(t)=t+1 and ord(t)<= t+gendata(i,"U")-1)  ,z(i,j)) =l= 1;`

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. One possible way would be defining two parameters as $UB$ and $LB$ in the pre-processing and filter the inner loop (on the summation) based on. Would you try that?

Comment: You mean like this:
Parameters LB  'lower limit';
           LB= t+1;

Parameters UB 'Upper limit';
           UB= j+gendata(i,"MUP")-1;

Uptime2..   u(i,j) + sum(j, $ (ord(j)>= LB AND ord(j)<= UB)  ,v(i,j)) =l= 1;

Comment: I meant something like this, just in the summation, you have to apply $ operator before comma. `sum((j)$ (ord(j)>= LB AND ord(j)<= UB, ...)`. I recommend that first defining a global set on the planning horizon, `set t /1...T/`, then `alias` that by other index like $k$.

Comment: I surely hope that GAMS produced a ton of error messages for this input. I usually start by studying the first error message, fix it, recompile and repeat.

Comment: Related:  [GAMS Sum over a subset](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/3991/491)

Answer (score -2):

```
eq(t) .. y(i,t) + sum(t $(ord(k)<=t+1 and ord(k)<= ord(t)+gendata(i,"U")-1)  ,z(i,k)) =l= 1;
```

Just make sure that k is a subset of t
This way
alias(k,t);

Comment: It would help if you could add an exposition to your code.